# Input string was not in a correct format for decimal type textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the above error on the following line of code whenever the text box is empty:

```
decimal Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text);
```

Can someone tell me where I might be wrong and give a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting the above error on the following line of code whenever
>   the text box is empty:

You should get an exception if you are using `Convert.ToDecimal` or `Decimal.Parse`, if you want to avoid exception and check if it contains any valid input then use [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
decimal Qty;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text, out Qty)
{
   //Some invalid input , empty string or invalid decimal number
}
else
{
  //valid decimal number
}
```

if you want to check your `TextBox.Text` for empty string, you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` Or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` *(provided with .Net framework 4.0 or higher)*  like:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text))
{
 //Don't do parsing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to happen?  If you want "" to mean QTY is 0, then do something like this:

```
Decimal qty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the default to 0 when there is nothing, this assumes you would want to do that.

```
decimal Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text == "" ?  "0" : txtQtyforAnalysis.Text);
```

Or just use the Decimal.TryParse

```
decimal Qty;

if (decimal.TryParse(txtQtyforAnalysis.Text, out Qty))
{
    //it worked
}
```